# How to overwrite valo-menu-responsive width-range rules?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-valo-theme

I need to modify standard valo theme in Vaadin app, so I overwrite standard rules in `mytheme.scss` ([like this](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-creating.html)), but I want to delete rules for valo-menu width-range in 801-1100px.

For this width-range exist 17 rules in `styles.css`. Should I overwrite everything rule or may be there are more simple way to do this?

I found just one [discussion](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/8819957) about this, but answer is not found.